# cucumber guice migration to version 1.2.4

Tags: java, cucumber, guice

I want migrate cucumber.runtime.java.guice 1.1.1 to 1.2.4

In version 1.1.1 GuiceFactory take this value `guiceModule=test.MyModule` in `src\test\resources\cucumber-guice.properties` file but do not work in version 1.2.4.

This project is a good example (https://github.com/rapaul/cucumber-jvm-guice-examples) in version 1.1.1 but I need use 1.2.4 in my project.

```
public class MyModule implements Module {

    @Override
    public void configure(Binder binder) {
        System.out.println("MyModule configure");
        StepsInterceptor stepsInterceptor = new StepsInterceptor();
        binder.bindInterceptor(any(), annotatedWith(SpeedRegulator.class), stepsInterceptor);
    }

}
```

**Please, how to use new version of GuiceFactory?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution:

**step 1:** create a class:

```
public class MyjectorSource implements InjectorSource {
    @Override
    public Injector getInjector() {
        return Guice.createInjector(Stage.PRODUCTION, CucumberModules.SCENARIO, new MyModule());
    }
}
```

**Step 2:** in cucumber.properties file:

guice.injector-source=test.MyjectorSource